# get jvm argument in the app when running gradle task

Tags: java, gradle

I am using `gradle` `application` plugin to run my `main` class.
When I do like this

```
gradle run -Dparameter=5
```

And try to get that argument `parameter` in my `main` function

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.getProperty("parameter")
}
```

It returns `null`.

How to pass `jvm` argument properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gradle -D` option sets the system property of the *Gradle process itself* and not the system property of the task you want to run.

You can use the `-P` (project property) option instead, but then you will need to get the property value in your gradle script and set the system property accrodingly:

```
if (project.hasProperty('myPropertyNameHere'))
    systemProperty('myPropertyNameHere', myPropertyNameHere)
```

Comment: Oh indeed. I forgot i different processes

Answer (score 2):

> If your application requires a specific set of JVM settings or system properties, you can configure the applicationDefaultJvmArgs property. These JVM arguments are applied to the run task and also considered in the generated start scripts of your distribution.

[Chapter 52. The Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html)

e.g.
    you can add

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs=["-Dparameter=5"]
```

in *build.gradle*